# Clean emacs REPL buffer

Tags: elisp, emacs24

What is the shortcut to clean the content in emacs repl
(`Alt-x ielm` to go there) buffer?
Note: I use this buffer to run elisp code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
(kill-buffer "*Messages*")
```

Adding this line to your program helps you to collect logs afresh.